# Questions about the beta function in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

When someone defines

$\beta(g)=\mu\frac{dg}{d\mu},\quad (1)$

he is implicitly assuming that the result of the rhs of this equation can be written only in terms of $g$ instead of $\mu$, which is not the case in general. How do we know that this holds? Can it be proved or this is an assumption indeed?

Secondly, I am struggling to understand how to calculate $\beta(g)$ in order to integrate (1), or at least to analyse it using dynamical systems techniques. In some places I saw people expanding $\beta$ as a series and then we solve (1) perturbatively, truncating the series to the desired order. But in this case, how do we calculate the coefficients of the series if we do not even know $\beta$ itself?

Comment: I don't understand why you say that we cannot write $\beta(g)$ as a function of $g$. We know $g(\mu)$ which we can invert to obtain $\mu(g)$. Then, wherever there is an explicit $\mu$ in $\beta$ just replace it with $\mu(g)$. You might argue that it's possible that $g(\mu)$ is not an invertible function, but that's certainly not true in perturbation theory. We can always solve for $\mu(g)$ order by order in $g$. Typically though, we never need to do any of this since $\beta$ just naturally turns out to be a function of $g$ directly.

Comment: @Prahar we do not always work perturbatively, do we? Anyway, even polynomials might not be invertible. The simplest case of $g(\mu)=\mu^2$ is not invertible in the whole real line.

Comment: Sure, but's never a function that you will ever get. The point is that at tree level, we have $g(\mu) = \mu^{\epsilon}g + {\cal O}(g^2)$ where $g$ is the physical coupling independent of $g$. The leading order result already fixes what solution I should be getting, when I invert the relationship. There is never an ambiguity perturbatively. Now, non-perturbatively is a more complicated problem and I am not sure how it resolves itself there.